# Ace Code Editor theme 403

Tags: javascript, plugins, http-status-code-403, ace-editor, code-editor

I have installed the code editor Ace onto my site (not locally). Now I am trying to load the theme 'ambiance' as shown in the available themes [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/lib/ace/theme).

```
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/ambiance");
```

However its failing to load returning a 403 response. I can see it being used with no issue on the ace kitchen sink page [here](http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html).

The other themes I have tried have loaded with no problem, so why am I getting 403 forbidden for `ambiance` since its clearly listed in the themes repo?

Answer (score 0):

Which installation instructions did you follow (link please)?

I did

```
git clone https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds.git
```

and the contents of `ace-builds/src` show no obvious problem with `theme-ambiance.js`.

All I can suggest is to debug the problem in a browser with great devtools, like Google Chrome.